# AroundInvoke not called with Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I created the following invoking class, which should be invoked, when an intercepted method is called:

```
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

@Interceptor
class TestAspect {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object log(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("AroundInvoke method called");
        return context.proceed();
    }
}
```

and this resource:

```
import javax.interceptor.Interceptors;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/test")
@Interceptors(TestAspect.class)
public class TestResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    public String test() {
        System.out.println("Resource method called");
        return new String("test");
    }
}
```

But I only get the log line from the resouce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Quarkus CDI Reference Guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#limitations),

> - @Interceptors is not supported

You'll need to add the `@Priority`, `@Interceptor`, and your binding annotation to your Interceptor class. See [here for an example](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/independent-projects/arc/tests/src/test/java/io/quarkus/arc/test/interceptors/LoggingInterceptor.java)

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate your interceptor either by defining it in beans.xml or adding @Priority(number) on your interceptor.